# Extract multiple files content in byte array using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using this solution to parse a file to byte array:
 
This works for me.
But I want to do this for multiple files

```js
var pniotApp = angular.module('pniotApp', []);

pniotApp.controller('pniotCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.saveContent = function ($fileContent) {
        $scope.content = $fileContent;
        console.log($scope.content);
    };
});

pniotApp.directive('onReadFile', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var fn = $parse(attrs.onReadFile);
            element.on('change', function (onChangeEvent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (onLoadEvent) {
                    var buffer = onLoadEvent.target.result;
                    var uint8 = new Uint8Array(buffer);     
                    var result = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < uint8.length; i++) {
                        result.push(uint8[i]);
                    }

                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        fn(scope, {
                            $fileContent: result
                        });
                    });
                };
                
                  reader.readAsArrayBuffer((onChangeEvent.srcElement || onChangeEvent.target).files[0]);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<input on-read-file="saveContent($fileContent)" type="file"/>
```

Now I want to do this for multiple files.
I try to replace the row `reader.readAsArrayBuffer((onChangeEvent.srcElement || onChangeEvent.target).files[0])`;
with:

```
 for (j = 0; j < (onChangeEvent.srcElement || onChangeEvent.target).files.length;j++)
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer((onChangeEvent.srcElement || onChangeEvent.target).files[j]);
```

But I get this errror 
 `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': The object is already busy reading Blobs.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': The object is
>   already busy reading Blobs.

I think its a right behavior. You should read one file after another and recreate  `Reader` a.e.

`var reader = new FileReader();`

So instead:

```
for (j = 0; j < (onChangeEvent.srcElement || onChangeEvent.target).files.length;j++)
   reader.readAsArrayBuffer((onChangeEvent.srcElement || onChangeEvent.target).files[j]);
```

It should be something like:

```
 var files = (onChangeEvent.srcElement || onChangeEvent.target).files;
for (j = 0; j < files.length;j++){
    readerEngine(files[j]);
    }
```

where `readerEngine` is:

```
function readerEngine(file_){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (onLoadEvent) {
      var buffer = onLoadEvent.target.result;
      var uint8 = new Uint8Array(buffer);     
      var result = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < uint8.length; i++) {
           result.push(uint8[i]);
       }

       scope.$apply(function () {
           fn(scope, {
              $fileContent: result
           });
         });
   };

   reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file_);
}
```

---

*didn't test it*